# Stirling's approximation fractional error

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

Given Stirling's approximation $lnN!$ is approximated by $NlnN-N+\frac{1}{2}lnN$.
I want to calculate the fractional error that comes from neglecting the third term $\frac{1}{2}lnN$ for N=10 and N=100.
I thought it would be enough to consider $\frac{\frac{1}{2}lnN}{NlnN-N+\frac{1}{2}lnN}$, but for N=10 I get 0.08, while, according to my professor, the answer is 0.05.
I have an identical issue with N=100, where I get 0.006 instead of 0.005.
Is there a problem with the way I am calculating the fractional error? I can't really see any other reason why I keep getting the wrong results.

Comment: Are you supoose to find the fractional error in approximating $\ln N!$ or the error in appoximating $N!$?

Comment: This question is about math, not physics.

Comment: Stirling's formula for $\ln N!$ is $$\ln N! = N \ln N -N+\tfrac12 \ln(2\pi N)$$ Note the $2\pi$.

Comment: I am supposed to find the fractional error in truncating the terms.

Comment: I put this question in physics as I am personally employing it in statistical physics.